# Query only part work with LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
$varCategory_RS_Search = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['Category'])) {
  $varCategory_RS_Search = str_replace('-', ' ',$_GET['Category']);
}
$query_RS_Search = sprintf("SELECT * FROM products WHERE Category LIKE %s" , GetSQLValueString("%" . $varCategory_RS_Search . "%", "text"));
$query_limit_RS_Search = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_RS_Search, $startRow_RS_Search, $maxRows_RS_Search);
$RS_Search = mysql_query($query_limit_RS_Search, $dconn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_RS_Search = mysql_fetch_assoc($RS_Search);
```

In the category field i want to search for Yamaha Digital Pianos, however I also would like to see the Yamaha Clavinova Digital pianos. The Category GET = Yamaha Digital Pianos. I only see the Yamha Digital Pianos I thought if  you would use LIKE it would select all the rows that contain the words Yamaha Digital Pianos, however it skips the ones with Clavinova in-between.

Any suggestion on how to ask for both Yamaha Digital Pianos and Yamaha Clavinova Digital Pianos. To see what I mean have a look at my website:`http://www.pianoandkeyboardshop.co.uk` and try to look at the yamaha Digital Pianos no Clavinovas are found unless you ask for them with Yamaha clavinova.
Any help welcome

Comment: You could try replacing every space in the **%s** variable with a % symbol such that your WHERE clause would be `WHERE Category LIKE '%Yamaha%Digital%Pianos%'`

Comment: Great that did the trick. I just replace the - with % nice easy solution. Thanks